# How to use .NET Action to execute a method with unknown number of parameters?

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, action

I want to execute some operations on a worker thread while displaying a progress bar to the user. I've created a class

```
public class ProgressBar
{
   public void StartAsyncTask(Action action)
   {
      Task t = new Task(action);
      t.start();
   }
}
```

I found out that I can send any method to the `StartAsyncTask` in the following way:

```
  ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
  pb.StartAsyncTask( () => DoSomething(15, "something"));

  public void DoSomething(int i, string s)
   {
      //do something
   }
```

First of all, I can't seem to understand what is and how is lambda expression - `() =>` - translated and how is the `Action` object passed a delegate with an unknown number of parameters.

I would like to use a `BackgroundWorker` with my ProgressBar but in this case I would need to invoke the action. So something like this:

```
void m_backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Action action = e.Argument as Action; //same action here passed through EventArgs
   //but already in a worker thread so no need for the Task object 

   //and now i need to somehow invoke the action object but i don't know what the parameters are. 

   action.Invoke( ? ); 
}
```

How is it possible in the first example to execute the action without knowing the parameters in `StartAsyncTask(Action action)` method?

Why do I need to know the parameters when invoking the action in this case?

Everything about how/why/when to use "`Action`" is pretty unclear to me even if I read MSDN documentation and some other threads here. 
Any information on this will help me.

Comment: You need to know the parameters when calling it.. otherwise (if it was possible not to pass parameters) the function won't have any parameters passed into it.. therefore making your first `parameter.Something` call throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think you're overthinking things a little bit. So let's start from the top:

1. A lambda expression is a notation to reference a method execution. Example:

   ```
    x => x + 3
   ```

   At the most basic level, this is representing a function that takes 1 input, `x`, and then returns a value equal to `x + 3`. So in your situation, your expression:

   ```
   () => DoSomething(15, "Something")
   ```

   Represents a method taking 0 parameters, and then invoking the method `DoSomething(15, "Something")`. The compiler is behind the scenes translating that into a `Func` or `Action` delegate for you. So it is in effect:

   ```
   new Action(delegate()
   {
       DoSomething(15, "Something")
   });
   ```

   The compiler rewrite of my simple expression above would be:

   ```
   new Func<int, int>(delegate(int x)
   {
       return x + 3;
   });
   ```
2. Next up, if you want to invoke an action later, the syntax for doing so is fairly straightforward:

   ```
   Action someMethod = new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("hello world"); }));
   someMethod(); // Invokes the delegate
   ```

   So if you have a given `Action` instance, simply invoking it with the `()` syntax is all you need, since `Action` is a delegate that takes 0 parameters and returns nothing.

   A function is similarly easy:

   ```
   Func<int, int> previousGuy = x => x + 3;
   var result = previousGuy(3); // result is 6
   ```
3. Lastly, if you want to pass along a method to invoke, and you don't have context for the parameters at that point, you can simply wrap your call in an action and invoke that later. For example:

   ```
   var myAction = new Action(() =>
        {
             // Some Complex Logic
             DoSomething(15, "Something");
             // More Complex Logic, etc
        });

   InvokeLater(myAction);

   public void InvokeLater(Action action)
   {
         action();
   }
   ```

   All of the data is captured in a closure of your method, and thus is saved. So if you can manage to pass along an `Action` to your event with the `e.Argument` property, all you would need to do would be to call `(e.Argument as Action)()`.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use `DynamicInvoke()` on that delegate (it takes `params object[] args` as argument)

```
action.DynamicInvoke(arg1, arg2, arg3 );
```